# SqlFieldsQuery with 'like' for IGNITE

Tags: sql, ignite

Stuck with a problem, I've got simple query:

```
private final static String QUERY_2_GET_ID = "select reg." + Cache.EVENT_DT +
                    " from " + CACHE_TABLE_NAME + " as reg" +
                    " where " + Cache.ID + " like '?%'");
```

I crucially need part with '?%' but it returns no result when I execute it with java code

```
FieldsQueryCursor<List<?>> queryResult = cache.query(QUERY_2_GET_ID.setArgs(id));
        List<List<?>> queryAll = queryResult.getAll();
```

It executes perfectly through SQL console though. Can anybody suggest why is it happening and maybe some solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `like concat(?, '%')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the comment, why can't you just do `" like ?").setArgs(id + "%")`? :)